# Creating a separate platform for books and research papers?

Tags: discussion, support, resource-recommendation, site-promotion

Physics Stack Exchange is doing well in terms of helping thousands of students and researchers in spreading the understanding of physics, with its world best question-and-answer scheme, but making this platform better, or converting our site to an all-in-one hotspot for pure physics related topics, is necessary.

I feel books, research papers, and other material are the most crucial step. Now is the time when we enrich our boundaries, so that users who want to learn from the site can gain more. I agree that people share the links of documents, but they are not in a collective base, and even some resources are not verified either even if they are correct or not!

So I put out a proposal for a physics library which will help many of us, so I am here for seeking some good suggestions and am asking the Stack Exchange council, including moderators, to look upon it!

Starting with me, I suggest we can make a separate room and which is under moderator! But the problem here is the same: to arrange the link and papers in a definite format.

Comment: Votes on Meta work differently. They are used to show agreement or disagreement.

Comment: IMO, people don't seem to disagree with creating such a library, it is just the extra effort (equivalent of creating a new SE site) which makes everyone think that it's a bad idea. And anyways, there are many other places on the internet where you couod get the books you want, for instance [archive.org](https://archive.org). If you are concerned with research papers, you can go to [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org). Creating such a collection would take huge efforts and at the same time, it would prove to be nothing more than redundant.

Comment: 1. This question suggests that we want to be something other than a place where people can ask questions about physics, i.e. *"converting our site to an all-in-one hotspot for pure physics related topics"*. This hasn't been our goal in the past, and you make no argument for why it should become it now. 2. After having failed to establish a good motivation, it is also entirely unclear what format exactly you are proposing. In particular your last paragraph is entirely incomprehensible to me. What does *"make a separate room and which is under moderator"* mean?

Comment: @ACuriousMind thanks for your response I will answer your last part first, so what I meant was people share there link of papers in the room, and they will be verified by moderator who is obviously good at physics

Comment: @ACuriousMind secondly we should have a place where we put some important book lines so that in future if anyone need them he can directly go to that room

Answer (score 6):

I have a lot of sympathy for this suggestion because we all have collections of links to useful books and articles (many of mine are links to questions on the Physics Stack Exchange).

But the problem is that bitter experience suggests that managing collections of links never works. Links go stale and after the initial burst of enthusiasm no-one keeps the list up to date. We would end up with just another collection of old and partly broken links.

We already have a book recommendations list in [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) and some of these are (legally) available online with a bit of Googling. While I like the idea of a definitive reference for online resources I just don't think it would work. Sorry :-(

Comment: I disagree with you sir @JohnRennie  the link you have mentioned is in question answer format, what I said that we should have this link and papers like we have in library I am ready to take this responsibility if community help!

Comment: The longer the Covid lock-down lasts the better this question will look.